# is there a triple axis option in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, linegraph

[triple axis example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPLZy.jpg)

Hi,
As I showed in picture attached. I have veriy simple dataset and I want to make triple axis line graph. Is it possible?

Comment: Not directly. You could likely approximate it with some calculated fields, a reference line and some annotations,  that would be a lot of effort to make a confusing viz. I’d look for alter designs to try first

Comment: Did you find an alter design?

Comment: Please help me about this. Proffesional tool like Tableau should have a solution for this.

Comment: You can only have two vertical axes - one on the left and one on the right. One approach you can do is to convert your measures to percentages if you have min/max bounds to work with. Then you can plot them on the same axis even if they are percentages of different underlying concepts